# ManyToOne relationship still getting eagerly fetched

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have read [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20JPA%20%40ManyToOne,what%20is%20instructed%20to%20do.) that `By default, the JPA @ManyToOne and @OneToOne annotations are fetched EAGERLY`.

My project is Spring Boot and uses Jackson.

My entities is getting fetched eagerly despite being annotated with lazy when I view the entities in the browser:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="HEALTH_CHECK")
public class HealthCheck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Bird bird;
```

And on Bird:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Bird {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
    private List<HealthCheck> listHealthCheck = new ArrayList<>();
    //others
```

I have tried using the derived query for `findById` and rolling my own:

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM HealthCheck h WHERE h.id = :id")
Optional <HealthCheck> getOneManually(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Either way a query on `HealthCheck` returns all the details of a bird.

Shouldn't my `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)` on HealthCheck override the default `EAGER` fetching?

Comment: How did you get to know it is fetchinge eagerly?
From postman or debugger or printing in console? If you do that, there is a chance it will be fetched eagerly as you are explicitly calling the whole object, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ManyToOne will be fetched lazily in your case - no doubts. The question is what your code is doing with the fetched entity `HealthCheck`. If it calls toString() or serialize a JSON string or you are showing the object in the IDE debugger window - all of this will cause Hibernate to fetch the `Bird` entity from the database with an additional select.

This is how lazy loading works - not fetch initially but fetch as soon as any getter called.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes its Spring and I am viewing in browser window from controller so Jackson has deserialised it. What would be the best way to see natively how changing the annotations changes what is fetched?
If Jackson does this what is the point of the annotation?

Comment: To see how it works first of all add property spring.jpa.show-sql=true. Then you can observe the select statements fired by Hibernate. You can write a test which calls your getOneManually method without doing anything with the result. Another test where the healthCheck.bird is printed out.

Comment: For a comprehensive guide see Baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading Chapter 6. lists the advantages and disadvantages of both lazy and eager loading.

Comment: but where would I put these test calls and how to fire them? On the controller methods or in App,class?

Comment: I was thinking of separate unit tests. Are you using some IDE like IntelliJ? Then it will be in the folder src/test/java

Comment: Can we take this to chat for a minute? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/254181/onetomany?tab=general

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254182/discussion-between-al-grant-and-mar-z).

Comment: I would like to know how to do this with the generated application class under src/test/java